# Make ScrollView size automatically up to a max height

Tags: react-native

I have a ScrollView that I want to grow as needed up to a certain amount, but it seems to always be the size of `maxHeight`:

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1, maxHeight: "50%"}}><Text>Top</Text></ScrollView>
<View style={{flex: 1}}><Text>Bottom</Text></View>
```

What I wanted was for the `Top` view to be pretty small.  And if the text there was longer, it would get taller as needed, but never taller than 50% of the screen.  Is that possible?

Comment: It's because your flex rules are making it equal height to the next view. `flex: 1` on both is effectively saying to make both 50%.

Comment: So, without the `flex:1` it would grow up to the 50% but would be smaller if the contents were smaller?

Comment: It would use the default height calculation for that component - in this case, a `ScrollView` always needs a bound height (so that it can calculate when it needs to enable scrolling etc.), however if it was a view that didn't internally scroll, then it would be driven by the computed height to a max of 50%.

Answer (score 37):

I have had to do something similar and found the solution to be:

```
<View style={{maxHeight:"50%"}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flexGrow:0}}>
        <Text>Top</Text>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
<View style={{flex: 1}}><Text>Bottom</Text></View>
```